# Does a pulled rubber band contain as much energy as a twisted rubber band?

Tags: energy, potential-energy, energy-storage

lets say I take two similar rubber bands.  One of them I pull until it almost reaches its breaking point.  The other I twist until it almost reached its breaking point.  Do both of these rubber bands contain (roughly) the same amount of energy?  It seems that the twisted band would contain more, but I am having a hard time justifying this.

Answer (score 2):

The band that is pulled contains much more elastic energy. This is because that band is stretched until breaking everywhere. The band that is twisted, only reaches it breaking point at the outer points of the cross section. The strain varies linearly with the distance from the center of the cross section and is zero at the center.

It may be worthy to note that there are two possibilities when you twist a band, if it is short it will twist around the center of it's cross section, and if it is long it will form a coil around another point. In both cases the strain varies linearly with the distance to the center of rotation.

Comment: Both are stretched to breaking point...

Comment: In case of torsion the stress is not the same in the whole cross section, please see figure 12.5 in: https://www.ct.upt.ro/users/MirelaAchim/Chapter12.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe they do possess the same amounts of elastic potential energy.  By stretching both rubber bands to breaking points, this means that both are stretched for equal distance, only that one loops around itself when twisted, while the other gets stretched far apart.  In the end, they will possess the same amounts of elastic potential energy.